# How do tier bonuses work?

Tags: payday-2

Each skill in Payday 2 has a "tier bonus" associated with it. For example, the "Die Hard" skill in the Enforcer tree has a tier bonus of "You gain 10% more health."

Under what conditions do I gain these bonuses? Do I need to spend a point in the skill?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You gain the bonuses for simply *unlocking* the skill tier. Take, for example, the tier 4 Ghost bonus. This is what it looks like 1 point before the tier is unlocked:

[image: Tier Bonus Locked]

And now I spend that extra 1 point to unlock tier 4:

[image: Tier Bonus Unlocked]

Comment: Incidentally, this is why I like dumping 20 points into Technician, for the +25% damage bonus, regardless of the build I'm going for.